# Math with numeric values derived from a dropdown field

Tags: drop-down, number, math

I had a **dropdown** field with a handle of `hLevel`, with only numeric values in it, anticipating that I could do math with the values in my template. But it seems I can't.

`{% set dif = subhead.hLevel - subhead.next.hLevel %}`

…returns an error message ending in:

> “could not be converted to int”

I found a thread convinced that `number_format` “[converts a string to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488946/intval-in-twig-template#comment81690544_24489675)”, so I tried that:

`{% set dif = subhead.hLevel|number_format - subhead.next.hLevel|number_format %}`

…but that doesn't work either. The error message changes to:

> “could not be converted to double”

Which doesn't surprise me as I did think that `number_format` is for float to formatted string conversion, not the other way round as well.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

When I change the field format to **number** everything works fine, but…

It would be good if there is an option to have **dropdown** field values be **parsed as numbers**, because from a UX perspective I would prefer that the field is a dropdown.

Or is there some workaround I've missed?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `subhead.hLevel.value`?

Comment: Doh! I am an idiot. That works. Thanks Olivier :)

Comment: @JonathanSchofield Happened to me, that's the only reason I picked up on it ;) Glad I could help